# Linux Mint 17 при установке не видит установленную Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Хочу поставить Linux Mint 17 как вторую ОС рядом с Win7. При установке весь диск виден как unallocated. Как установить Linux, чтобы не затереть файлов Windows?

Также хотел узнать, случайно нажал установить на unallocated диск, после чего резко вытянул диск с Linux Mint 17, но некоторые данные он уже потёр. Теперь Windows не запускается и выдает **No bootable device insert boot disk and press any key**. Если MBR восстановить, всё нормально будет или уже нужно Windows переустанавливать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сильно зависит от того, что именно успел стереть установщик. Он вполне мог успеть горхнуть не только MBR, но и загрузчик винды, да и вообще всю таблицу разделов. Загрузитесь с LiveCD и проверьте, что осталось от вашего диска.